# Вращение линии в QT

Tags: qt, c++

Новичок в qt, хочу сделать форму с вращающейся линией (версия qt - 4.8.1).
Создал свой класс, координаты вращающего конца считаю с помощью полярных координат:

```
MyLabel::MyLabel(QWidget * parent):QLabel(parent), phi(0.0),x(210),y(0)
{
    startTimer(1000/60);
}

void MyLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter p(this);
    p.setPen(QPen(Qt::white, 5, Qt::SolidLine));
    QLine line(200, 200, x+200, y+200);
    p.drawLine(line);
}

//приращение угла
void MyLabel::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{
    phi = phi + 1;
    if (phi > 360)
        phi = phi - 360;
    update_xy();
}

//подсчёт пск
void MyLabel::update_xy()
{
    double phi_rad, tmp1, tmp2;
    phi_rad = phi / 180 * 3.14159265358979323846;
    tmp1 = qCos(phi_rad);
    tmp2 = qSin(phi_rad);

    x = 210*tmp1; //210 - длина линии
    y = 210*tmp2;
    update();
}
```

Но возникла проблема - при значениях длины линии, превышающих 200, линия стала вести себя  непредсказуемо. Т.е. при значениях угла phi  больших 100 градусов, она начинает плясать непонятным образом, пока ход линии не нормализуется в значении phi=0. По всей видимости, по каким-то неведанным причинам идет неверный подсчёт синусов-косинусов, но почему тогда нормально работает на значениях длины линии, меньших 200 - совершенно неясно. Может кто-нибудь сможет подсказать, в чем проблема?

Comment: А при длине линии меньше 200 - все ок?


А если центр перенести с 200,200 в 300,300 , то проблемы будут при длине линии в 300?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в элементарной невнимательности. Просто необходимо цифры не забивать ручками, а выделять в переменные, и с ними не возникнет путаницы. Вот рабочий код:

```
MyLabel::MyLabel(QWidget * parent):QLabel(parent), phi(0.0),length(400),x(length),y(0)
{
    startTimer(1000/60);
}

void MyLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    double coordinateX = 740, coordinateY = 540;
    QPainter p(this);
    p.setPen(QPen(Qt::white, 5, Qt::SolidLine));
    QLine lol(coordinateX, coordinateY, x+coordinateX, y+coordinateY);
    p.drawLine(lol);
}

void MyLabel::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{
    // приращение угла
    phi = phi + 3.6;
    if (phi > 360)
        phi = phi - 360;
    update_xy();
}

void MyLabel::update_xy()
{
    double phi_rad, tmp1, tmp2;
    phi_rad = phi / 180 * 3.14159265358979323846;
    tmp1 = qCos(phi_rad);
    tmp2 = qSin(phi_rad);
    x = length*tmp1;
    y = length*tmp2;
    update();
}
```